# Sorting on Pig Latin

Tags: sorting, apache-pig, hadoop2

I'm testing the following example from Apache Pig docs:

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#order-by

but the sort function seems to be not working. Any idea?

```
$ pig -version
Apache Pig version 0.14.0 (r1640057) 
compiled Nov 16 2014, 18:02:05


grunt> a= load 'data' as (c1:int, c2:int, c3:int);
grunt> describe a;
a: {c1: int,c2: int,c3: int}
grunt> dump a;
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)
(8,4,3)
grunt> result = order a by c1 desc;
grunt> dump result; 
(8,4,3)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(4,2,1)
(1,2,3)
(7,2,5)
grunt> result = order a by c2 desc;
grunt> dump result;
(8,4,3)
(7,2,5)
(4,2,1)
(1,2,3)
(4,3,3)
(8,3,4)
grunt> result = order a by c3 desc;
grunt> dump result;                
(7,2,5)
(4,3,3)
(8,4,3)
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the data using default delimiter(`tab`) but your actual input data is not properly delimited by tab. Can you make sure that your input data fields are delimited by tab in the file `'data'`.

In the below example each input field is delimited by tab and its working fine.

```
data:
1<TAB>2<TAB>3
4<TAB>2<TAB>1
8<TAB>3<TAB>4
4<TAB>3<TAB>3
7<TAB>2<TAB>5
8<TAB>4<TAB>3

grunt> a= load 'data' as (c1:int, c2:int, c3:int);
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)
(8,4,3)
grunt> result = order a by c1 desc;
grunt> dump result;
(8,3,4)
(8,4,3)
(7,2,5)
(4,2,1)
(4,3,3)
(1,2,3)
grunt> result = order a by c2 desc;
grunt> dump result;
(8,4,3)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(7,2,5)
grunt> result = order a by c3 desc;
grunt> dump result; 
(7,2,5)
(8,3,4)
(1,2,3)
(4,3,3)
(8,4,3)
(4,2,1)
```